# Mysql events using cpanel cronjob

Tags: mysql, linux, cron, cpanel

We have a queueing system that was developed by our previous developer, and the truncate command was manually executed to the mysql query. We cant use event scheduler on cpanel so the best option we have is to use cronjob. however, we have no idea on how to execute linux command.

Can someone help me to make a linux query for this?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE counter_logs_vxphl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the command using the following command, replace `{USER}` with the username and `{PASSWORD}` with the password, if you want to specify the host just add `-h {HOSTNAME}`

```
mysql -u {USER} -p{PASSWORD} -e "TRUNCATE TABLE counter_logs_vxphl;" > mysql-truncate.log
```